# Joined tables is not getting created in JPA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

**SOLUTION :**
 I have figured out a work around for this problem. I ran my main class using a shell script and I also enhanced all my classes using the same shell script here is the code.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Compile and Run the OpenJPA test program
#
cp=.
cp=$cp:lib/mysql-connector-java.jar
cp=$cp:lib/openjpa-2.0.1.jar
cp=$cp:lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar
cp=$cp:lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
cp=$cp:lib/serp-1.13.1.jar
cp=$cp:lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
cp=$cp:lib/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.1.jar
#
echo "Compiling"
javac -cp $cp *.java */*.java
echo "Enhancing"
java -cp $cp org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer nu/InstrumentType.java nu/Instrument.java nu/Laboratory.java nu/MedicalLaboratory.java
echo "Running"
java -cp $cp test
```

***As you can see nu is my package name and my class that needs to be enhanced is followed by / 
test is my main class.
I dont know but enhancing this way instead of using ecplise built in enhancer works.***

```
QUESTION :
```

***This is my file layer hierarchy***

[image: This is my file layer hierarchy]

I am using openjpa

Instrument , InstrumentType, Laboratory, MedicalLaboratory are my classes.
I have created joined tables/referenced tables inside my Instrument class and InstrumentType class which is not getting created.

I have the following code inside my Instrument class

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="type", nullable=false)
    public InstrumentType type;


    @ManyToMany(fetch=EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="usedBy",
           joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="instrument"),
           inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="laboratory"))
    public Set<Laboratory> UsedBy;

public void setUsedBy(Set<Laboratory> UsedBy) {
    this.UsedBy = UsedBy;
    }
```

I have the following code inside my InstrumentType class

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=EAGER)
    @Column(name="name")
    @CollectionTable(name="InstrumentName", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="type"))
    public Set<String> names;
```

This is the output ie the tables that I am able to see in my Navicat. As you can see only the 4 tables are getting created and not the joined tables.

[image]

**This is my main class**

```
public class main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create the new objects to be persisted.
    Instrument i = new Instrument();
    InstrumentType it = new InstrumentType();
    Laboratory l = new Laboratory();
    MedicalLaboratory ml = new MedicalLaboratory();


    // Configure and create the factory.
    java.util.Map<Object,Object> map = new java.util.HashMap<Object,Object>();
    map.put("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", "root");
    map.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "root");
    map.put("openjpa.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test123");
    map.put("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    map.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "buildSchema");
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test123", map);

        // Create a new EntityManager from the EntityManagerFactory. The
        // EntityManager is the main object in the persistence API, and is
        // used to create, delete, and query objects, as well as access
        // the current transaction
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        // Begin a new local transaction so that we can persist a new entity
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // Create and persist a new Message entity
        em.persist(i);
        em.persist(it);
        em.persist(l);
        em.persist(ml);


        // Commit the transaction, which will cause the entity to
        // be stored in the database
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        // It is always good practice to close the EntityManager so that
        // resources are conserved.
        em.close();
        factory.close();

}
}
```

This is the error I am getting not able to understand it.

```
73  test123  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.0.1
164  test123  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary".
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:584)
    at nu.main.main(main.java:50)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.1-r422266:989424 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1963)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1479)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:925)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:560)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at nu.MedicalLaboratory.pcProvideField(MedicalLaboratory.java)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.provideField(StateManagerImpl.java:3135)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2956)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:40)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1047)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2077)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1955)
    ... 5 more
```

**I am just trying to get the joined tables to be displayed so that I can query on them. It would be great if anyone can point out why the joined tables are not getting created.**

Comment: Have you tried deleting your existing tables and having OpenJPA try to recreate them again?

Comment: I've never used OpenJPA but looking at this: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_mapping.html#ref_guide_mapping_synch - do you think that 'buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)' could be relevant in your case?

Comment: @rick Yes I have tried that .. does nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are currently having is pointed out in the lines of exception below:

```
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:560)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at nu.MedicalLaboratory.pcProvideField(MedicalLaboratory.java)
```

Can you post the full mapping classes you have, also, what are the Entity Relationships you are trying to map? you should probably build one ER class first, with no ER fields, then choose the 'simplest' ER relationship, and map that next. Its not clear from your listings, what is being mapped?

Comment: when I try to enhance it using eclipse enhancer it does not work, but when I enhance it using command line it works

Comment: Problem was with eclipse built in enhancer

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh so, this problem is solved? What do you mean by 'eclipse built in enhancer'?

Comment: I have pasted the shell script that I used to run my java program. I enhanced my classes this way instead of using eclipse built in enhancer which you can download from the open jpa site.